# Symfony 3 serializer problems

Tags: javascript, php, serialization, doctrine-orm, symfony

Hello I am creating an API REST on Symfony 3.1.

I have got a problem Serializing and object.

These is the error it returns to me.

```
A circular reference has been detected (configured limit: 1).
```

Stack overflow link I have read without any result.

- [Converting a Symfony2 PHP entity object for use within Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068305/converting-a-symfony2-php-entity-object-for-use-within-javascript)
- [A circular reference has been detected (configured limit: 1) Serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272012/a-circular-reference-has-been-detected-configured-limit-1-serializer)

These is the documentation which I readed for try the seialize my obtject.

- [Symfony how to use Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html)
- [Symfony Serializaer Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Here is the code for fill $employees:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$dql = " SELECT e FROM BackendBundle:Employees e 
         INNER JOIN BackendBundle:Companies c 
         WITH e.idCompany = c.idCompany 
         WHERE c.idUser = ?1";                
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$query->setParameter(1,$user);
$employees = $query->getResult();
```

I Tryied these thing:

1. First proof

   ```
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;

    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
    $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers,$encoders);                
    $data = $serializer->serialize($employees, 'json');
   ```
2. The sencond proof

In these proof I readed by default on Symfony 3 Serialzer is deseabe. For that I modified these files:

> app/config/config.yml

```
framework:
#esi:             ~
#translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
secret:          "%secret%"
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
#serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_hosts:   ~
trusted_proxies: ~
session:
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
    handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
    save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true
assets: ~
serializer:
    enabled: true
    enable_annotations: true
```

The unic important thing on here are the last lines where I active the serializer.

> app/config/servces.yml

```
services:    
get_set_method_normalizer:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: serializer.normalizer }
```

> src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
<?php
$serializer = $this->get('serializer');
$json = $serializer->serialize($employees,'json');
```

And little more proof where there is not much difference between you are reading and it.

Please if someone know how serialize an object on Symfony 3. I wat trying it all morning with the same error.

```
A circular reference has been detected (configured limit: 1).
```

Comment: this link is exactly describing your issue and how to solve it: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references

Comment: Thanks that setCircularReferenceHandler solve all my problems. Do you know how can I close these post?

Comment: I will provide the link as a solution and you can accept my answer.

Comment: I do not know how to do that. I only know post xD

Comment: glad you found it, you can as well hit the 'arrow up' button if you want to upvote my answer as well.

Comment: Sorry my reputation is not high enough for do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that serializing Employees is serializing their company which again is having a reference to Employees, a perfect circular reference.

You can handle these circular references in Symfony's Serializer e.g. by catching the CircularReferenceException or by using custom callable in setCircularReferenceHandler and only serialize attributes which are not referencing back to the original entity.

See [Symfony's documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references) for a detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

```
$normalizers->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
        return $object->getId();
    });
```

add this bro after you make the instance of your ObjectNormalizer() .
It work perfectly for me !